# When writing a command and waiting for a response in a BLE Device, do you write in the characteristics or descriptor?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I currently doing an app in with BLE Features, but unfortunately, when I try to write in a characteristic it always return a the value of what I write in the characteristics and not the measurements/data that I needed.

I am expecting to get the measurements of some BLE Devices

Here is the relevant part of the documentation

This is the code I've been using

```
 for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in service.characteristics) {
        c.write([0x61]);
        if (c.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
          final subscription = c.onValueReceived.listen((value) {
            print(c.lastValue);
            print(value);``
            print(c.value);
          });

          widget.device.cancelWhenDisconnected(subscription);
          await c.setNotifyValue(true);
```

}
}

Comment: Does the characteristic allow reading and writing or is there a separate characteristic on which you would receive your answer? Have you tried this using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: the characteristics allow write and notify. and yes I've tried using the nRF Connect but its still the same after I write in the characteristics with notifications enabled the value I get is still the same value of what I wrote in the characteristics I can't get the measurements I needed. but in the documentation of the device, I think I need to send a command before getting a response. btw Im using flutter-blue-plus. Thank you

Comment: Can [edit] your question and add the part of your code where you write and read the values as well as a link to the device documentation?

Comment: I've edited my question and added the code and some part of the documentation. I Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Reading the documentation I do not see where it states what you need to send to the device to receive the heart rate measurements. Under format it just states the response format. That's different for "Clear/Delete all Memory" for example.

Comment: the [0x61] that says there is not a command? so I just need to read the characteristic or just read the value? but when I do that I get nothing.

Comment: The documentation is quite confusing. It reads like you need to send something to receive the data. but it does not mention what exactly needs to be send. Could you maybe reach out to the manufacturer? Are you allowed to tell us which device this is exactly? Maybe I can find something related myself

Comment: I will try that and get back to you. Again, Thank you very much